# Matching all occurrences of "keyword-hashtag" couples

Tags: python, regex

I have several keywords that are followed with `#` and digits. How can I obtain **all** hashtags and digits that follows keywords? My keywords are not limited to two.

Input --> Output

```
"comes #12" --> #12
"comes #12\r\n" --> #12
"comes #12." --> None
"comes #12qwerty" --> None

"come #13" --> #13
"come #13\r\n" --> #13

"comed #12, come #13" --> #12 and #13
"comed #12, comes #13" --> #12 and #13
```

Answer (score -1):

The regex you are looking for:

```
import re
my_regex = r"#\d\d*"
```

this matches `#` at first, then one digit with `\d` and then zero or more digits after the first one with `\d*`. So you can:

```
my_output = re.findall(my_regex, my_text)
print(my_output)
```

edit:
provided a regex that matches non proceeding digits.

```
my_regex = (?<=comes|come|comed)((#\d\d*)!?\D+)
```

Comment: This also catches the hashtags after not keyword strings such as `badstring #13` which I do not want

Comment: I tried `(?:(?<=comes)|(?<=come)|(?<=comed)\s)(#\d\d*)` this, but it matches one occurrence only.

Comment: Without knowing your keywords I can't really help you further then... Your example shows three different keywords and all have a valid output. 

Edit: I do see now that you have an example of a #12qwerty that you dont want to match. My solution also matsches that. I'll look into that and provide a solution that only matches hashtag-digit combinations.

Comment: `(?<=comes|come|comed)\s(#\d\d*)` matches with keywords, but cannot spot if hashtag has proceeding non-digits or not

Comment: from python regex cheatsheet: A(?!B) | Negative lookahead assertion. This
matches the expression A only if it is not
followed by B. so I've edited the post with the correct answer.